# A html page with a large number of parameters in Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket, parameter-passing

Just to mention, I use Wicket to implement this program.

I have a html page which requires a maximum of 10 parameters in order to retrieve some exisiting values from the previous page.

However, all of this parameters wont get their input in every situation. There are sometimes only 1 value need to be passed in and other times it requires 10 values.

I could actually do as the follows when a page is being created :

```
    setResponsePage(new htmlPage("string", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
```

and

```
   setResponsePage(new htmlPage("string", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7", "string8", "string9", "string10"));
```

but is this a bad practice? is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I decided to pass an object as a parameter and called its method. It looks must cleaner now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `PageParameters` to achieve this cleanly